# problem with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf can´t use bootstrap styles

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, laravel-dompdf, barryvdh

Library it´s:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

i´m trying to create pdf in my app with laravel 10.20. I created my blade and all content it´s ok.

[image]

I have any rows, columns, etc and all my content when i access to route that i can show my blade, it´s ok.

In my controller i have this code:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('Pdfs.precontract', ['precontrato' => $personalDataPrecontract])
                            ->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')
                            ->setOption('zoom', 1.2)
                            ->setOption('footer-center', '')
                            ->setOption('footer-font-size', 5);
            $pdf->set_base_path("/public/css/");

            $path = public_path('/storage/pruebas');
            $fileName =  'precontrato.pdf' ;
            $pdf->save($path . '/' . $fileName);
            $pdf->download($fileName);
```

My problem, it´s when i create my pdf with controller, not load my head styles. In my blade, i haver any includes (head, footer, etc) in my head, i have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style_pdf_pre.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 mt-3">
```

My bootstrap version it´s in PDFs, `v4.6.2` i trayed with `3.3.7`, but i have same problem.

When generate my pdf, i can show it so.

[image]

I haven´t got rows.. columns...

Anybody can say me that i´m doing wrong? Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` does not support `boostrap` yet and it supports `CSS 2.1` selector syntaxes. You can find the dompdf supported CSS selector syntaxes [here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility).

But if insist on using bootstrap you may try:

```
$pdf->setBasePath(public_path());
```

Then in you HTML use:

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

But then you're likely to encounter another issue that is `col-md-12` will result in a **div outside the pdf sheet**. And to fix that you need to set the DPI in the following format:

```
$pdf = new \Dompdf\Options();
$pdf->setDpi(150);
$dompdf = new \Dompdf($pdf);
```

However, for PDF's with little design that can be pulled through small amount of CSS I prefer to do the design manually.
You may take some idea from the [this](https://github.com/Wakil18/Basic-HTML-and-CSS2.1-Invoice) repository that I've created for simple invoices and often use it.

Comment: thanks for your response, but not run your response

Comment: @scorpions77 What's happening? Getting any errors?

Comment: yes, for example ```Class "Dompdf" not found```

Comment: i resolve my problem installing  laravel-snappy and configure it in windows and adding in my head blade ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">```
    
        ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">```